# Integrate java app to windows context menu

Tags: java, contextmenu, bandwidth

i want to dev an app that can integrate to windows context menu when i right click to file or folder like this image :

[image]

(sorry because i cant upload image directly)

i have searched everywhere on google but i cant find the solution.
can anyone tell me what i should do to dev an app like that? can i dev it by java or C#?

and 1 more thing, i want to dev my app to download or upload a file with the bandwidth i set, so how can i do it

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "Search everywhere" ? For C# it's not hard to find, for example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus . Do a search on "Shell context menu" for example.

Comment: i search for java because i want to try to dev it on java, and i dont find any solution, so if there is no solution so i will try dev-ing it on C# :) (sorry for my bad EL)

Comment: Ok! For Java I can't help you ;)